# How should I make Xdebug run for only CLI php not for UI

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I want to set Xdebug configuration as where it should work for just CLI not for browser.
The reason is I want to test this tool for CLI only. Below is the **xdebug.ini**

```html
#this line will be added automatically
zend_extension = /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
#add the following
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value = 3236
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /net/tmp/
```

Comment: Do you have a separate php.ini for your cli and webapp?

Comment: No I don't have

Comment: Have you tried `xdebug.remote_autostart=1`

Comment: Depending on your setup that may or may not cause xdebug to always run in the browser so you'll have to test it

Comment: Yes This doesnot satisfy my Problem. What I want is I do not want xdebug to do profiling my web pages but do profile my Crons and cli php files

Comment: Yeah that might work for you, for my setup remote_autostart doesn't affect webpages, no idea what causes that difference though

Comment: There is difference here @Shardj in Remote is I need to point to some x server for profiling. this will work for both CLI and web page due to "profiler_enable" this makes it active for all where as "profiler_enable_trigger" helps to control the same via GET/POST request or HTTP headers.

Comment: You should also have a look at `xdebug.remote_enable=0`

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot have separate php.ini files for php-cli and php-fpm/apache/etc you can set `xdebug.profiler_enable=0` and the profiling will not start. Then set `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1` as you have and optionally `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value = 3236`.

Then when starting the php-cli command add an environment variable XDEBUG_PROFILE=3236. This will start profiling.

```
XDEBUG_PROFILE=3236 php script.php
```

Note that profiling can be triggered also with a web request, but the person doing this would need to know your "trigger value".

Documentation here: https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler